# APDU command to check how many tries the chip made in the PIV application and verificatives

Tags: command, apdu

I'm working with smartcard chips and using its PIV app,  `{00 A4 P1 P2 Le Data Lc}` all the verficatives are fine `{00 20 P1 P2 Le Data Lc}` and `{00 21 P1 P2 Le Data Lc}`.

But as you know the piv apllication have a counter of failed tries; in this case `00 20` have a `3` and `00 21` have `15` as number of failed tries before it locks.

I want to know if there is any APDU command available that actually reads the number of tries, without increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the exact command with no Command Data, i.e. the Lc is '00'.
The card shall return SW1-SW2='63 CX', where X denotes remaining tries.

The APDU shall look like the following:

```
Command APDU: 00 20 P1 P2 00
Response APDU: 63 C3
```

NOTE: I have been using this for INS '20', but never tried for INS '21'.